# How to change the order of the messages in a channel?

Tags: model-checking, promela, spin

I have this code need to amend so that the channels can reorder the messages and I have to add mechanism to cope with this

```
chan linkA = [10] of {byte};
chan linkB = [10] of {byte};
proctype sender ()
{ byte n;
do
:: n<10 -> linkA!n*n; n++;
linkB!n*n; n++
:: else -> break
od
}
proctype receiver (chan link)
{ byte m,i; byte result[5];
do
:: i<5 -> link?m -> result[i]=m; i++
:: else -> break
od
}
init
{
run sender ();
run receiver (linkA);
run receiver (linkB)
}
```

I created new process reorder has a channel parameter(linkC)
In the reorder process the channel will receive two variables (byte x) which represent the data byte and (byte s) the index of the result.
As consequence, the declaration of the channels to receiver have been changed to receive {byte,byte}

Also, I changed receiver process

```
1   chan linkA = [10] of {byte , byte};
2   chan linkB = [10] of {byte, byte};
3   
4   proctype sender ()
5   { byte n;
6   do
7   :: n<10 -> linkA!!n*n; n++;
8              linkB!!n*n; n++
9   :: else -> break
10  od
11  }
12  proctype reorder (chan linkC)
13  {
14  byte x;
15  byte s;
16  end1:
17  do
18  :: linkC ? x,s -> linkC !x,s
19  od
20  }
21  proctype receiver (chan link)
22  { byte m,i; 
23  byte result[5];
24  byte from_proc;
25  do
26  :: i<5 -> link?from_proc,m -> result[i]=from_proc; i++
27  :: else -> break
28  od
29  }
30  init
31  {
32  run sender ();
33  run reorder (linkA);
34  run reorder (linkB);
35  run receiver (linkA);
36  run receiver (linkB)
37  }
```

to cope with the reorder, I added !! (sorted send operation)

but the code does not work as I wish and I do not know where is the problem.

Comment: Your specification is unclear. What does it mean *"reorder the messages"* in this context? What is the expected order? Why is there an extra process `reorder`, what should it do? Why are you using the sorted send `!!` when you are already generating the values in *increasing order*? Should you wait all messages to be in the queue, sort them, and only after read them or not?. You should explain **"the code does not work as I wish "** a bit better if you want to be helped.

Comment: I want to change the index order of the array to be in random way not increasing. The reorder process to receive the index number and reorder it in random way and send it to receiver.

Comment: Should all messages be in the queue of messages before you re-order them, or not? Note that in the latter case the messages might not be re-ordered in some executions. Do you really want a process `reorder` or do you accept a solution without such process? Did you consider using the *random receive*?

Comment: yes it should be in the queue of the messages

Comment: I used the reorder from an example code I had but the main thing is to make the order random by using any method

Answer (score 0):

Your solution has the problem that the messages are initially sorted by `sender` in the exact order of their creation, which corresponds also to an increasing value order. The `reorder` process in your model sample doesn't do much, actually. It takes the first message from the queue and it places it at the end of the queue. If the queue contains `k` messages, after `k` steps the messages are sorted again according to the initial order.

I see three possible approaches to deal with this problem:

- directly generate the messages in a randomized order, so that there is no need to reorder them later
- place a randomly generated seed in the first field of each message and post-pone the `receiver` execution up until when all messages are in the queue, so that the messages are randomly placed in the message queue when using the **sorted send**
- use the **random receive**, together with `eval(idx)`, so as to make the `receiver` read the messages in randomized order, even though the messages in the queue are perfectly sorted. This eliminates the problem of synchronizing the `receiver` with the `sender`, but it requires the `receiver` to know something more about the content of the message like, e.g., the `idx` of each message.

---

A solution following the second approach described above follows:

```
chan linkA = [10] of {byte, byte};
chan linkB = [10] of {byte, byte};
bool synch = false;

proctype sender ()
{
    byte i;
    byte idx;

    for (i : 0 .. 5) {
        int n = 2*i;
        select(idx:0..255);
        printf("Sender: <%d, %d> to linkA\n", idx, n*n);
        linkA!!idx,n*n;
        n = n + 1;
        select(idx:0..255);
        printf("Sender: <%d, %d> to linkB\n", idx, n*n);
        linkB!!idx,n*n;
    }
    synch = true;
}

proctype receiver (chan link)
{
    byte i, idx;
    byte result[6];

    /* wait until all messages in the queue */
    synch;

    for (i : 0 .. 5) {
        link?idx,result[i];
        printf("Receiver(%d): <%d, %d>\n", _pid, idx, result[i]);
    }
}

init
{
    run sender ();
    run receiver (linkA);
    run receiver (linkB)
}
```

The output is:

```
~$ spin test.pml 
          Sender: <0, 0> to linkA
          Sender: <3, 1> to linkB
          Sender: <2, 4> to linkA
          Sender: <1, 9> to linkB
          Sender: <1, 16> to linkA
          Sender: <0, 25> to linkB
          Sender: <0, 36> to linkA
          Sender: <0, 49> to linkB
          Sender: <4, 64> to linkA
          Sender: <2, 81> to linkB
          Sender: <0, 100> to linkA
          Sender: <0, 121> to linkB
                  Receiver(3): <0, 25>
                  Receiver(3): <0, 49>
              Receiver(2): <0, 0>
                  Receiver(3): <0, 121>
              Receiver(2): <0, 36>
                  Receiver(3): <1, 9>
                  Receiver(3): <2, 81>
              Receiver(2): <0, 100>
                  Receiver(3): <3, 1>
              Receiver(2): <1, 16>
              Receiver(2): <2, 4>
              Receiver(2): <4, 64>
4 processes created
```

Notice that `idx` is randomly generated and that the model admits executions in which every message has a different `idx` value.